# Interactive CSS tooltip box containing HTML

Tags: html, css, tooltip, css-transitions

After some browsing I found a code which does what I'd like up to a degree. I'm able to mouse over some text and have a tooltip box appear which contains HTML so it can have images, links, etc in it.

I had it working perfectly and easily in jQuery. The problem is, it's for an eBay description and jQuery won't load on the site, thus it's broken. Which means I have to do it in CSS.

Below is my code - it works with the problem that the box appears when you mouse over where it is, not just when you mouse over the text when you want it to appear - also the cursor has stopped changing to the help symbol for some reason.

I've built a JSFiddle as it seems to make sense for this (though the help cursor does work here, so that must be something else in my longer code)

http://jsfiddle.net/t19vkd5k/

```
.tiptext {
    width: auto;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 14px;
    /*line-height: 175%;*/
    color: rgb(39, 44, 45);
    cursor: help !important;
    position: relative;
}

.description {
    border:1px solid #e3e3e3;
    background: white;
    width:auto;
    max-width:275px;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', Helvetica;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: rgb(39, 44, 45);
    font-size: 13px;
    top:29px;
    left: 120px;
    z-index:500;
    opacity:0;
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.9s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.9s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.9s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.9s ease-out;
    transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}

.tiptext:hover .description { /* display tooltip on hover */
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tiptext">Hover over me<div class="description" style="text-align:center;">and this box appears with full html support like links to  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a><br>the problem is, this box also appears when you mouse over where it would be.</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the input @1l13v but I edited a suggestion using visibility and some other hacks and got something working perfectly, which for anyone searching is also 100% eBay compatible too. An interact CSS tool tip box which can contain links or pictures and only appears on mouseover. It has animation for fading in quickly and fading out slowly and it also has a question mark for in my case the help boxes.

I ended up with

```css
.tiptext {cursor: help;font-family:'ProximaNova',Helvetica;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;font-size: 14px;line-height: 172%;color:rgb(39, 44, 45);}

.description {border:1px solid #e3e3e3;background: white;width:auto;max-width:275px;height:auto;padding:10px;font-family: 'ProximaNova', Helvetica;font-weight: 300;color: rgb(39, 44, 45);font-size: 13px;z-index: 500;position: absolute;margin-left: 50px;margin-top: 20px;cursor: default;display: inline-block;}

.tiptext > .description {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.4s,opacity 0.4s linear;
}

.tiptext:hover > .description {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiptext"><div class="description" style="width:300px">This text is in the tool tip box and can include HTML just like any standard div container, allowing you to add links or photos. It only fades away when you move away from tooltip box or the link so you can interact with it.</div>This is the text you hover over for the tool tip to appear.</div>
```

And a fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/a64gpc40/

Answer (score 0):

You should place your `Hover over me` in separate div like this:

```
<div class="target"> Hover over me </div>
```

and when you hover the `.target` class only then show the tooltip, like this:

```
.target:hover + .description { /* display tooltip on hover */
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
      transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t19vkd5k/1/)

Comment: Now you've got the opposite problem in that the pop up box isn't interactive as once you mouse over it, it disappears. I'm not sure if its going to be possible to keep it there to mouse over as well...

Comment: well that's the default tooltip behavior. Until you stay with mouse over `Hover over me` you will see the tooltip, otherwise it will disappear slowly

Comment: I know, I could get that behaviour without the extra div though by making it hide when hovered over. I want the tooltip to be interactive, hence why I want it to contact html links etc

I wonder if there's a way to have the tooltip appear and then once its appeared stay there if you mouse over the tooltip (which is now visible) but if its not visible you can't mouse over JUST the tooltip to make it appear (the original bug)

Comment: Unfortunately not no, thats the limitation, eBay wont allow Jquery. If its not possible to make it stay hovered once it appears then I guess I'll have to rethink the interactions and just purely make them informative rather than interactive.

Comment: then I suggest you to try with plain javascript or css preprocessor

Comment: I found this - but it'll mean starting again to get it working really - http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-create-script-free-css3-tooltips--webdesign-3322